# How to dynamically change border color when the error occur in UWP XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

I had bind the error method property with text-block so that when error occurs it is shown down the textbox in the form. But i also want to change the background color of the textbox when the error occurs. But i don't know how to bind the border-brush property dynamically with text-box when the error occur. I have shared the small portions of my code.

XAML code

```
             <TextBlock
            Margin="0 110 0 12"
            Style="{StaticResource Label}"
            Text="Name"
            />

            <TextBox
               Margin="0 0 300 0" MaxLength="20" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsNameValid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
  private string IsNameValid_;
    public string IsNameValid
    {
        get => this.IsNameValid_;
        set => SetProperty(ref this.IsNameValid_, value);
    }
  public async Task RegisterPatientInfo()
    {
        
        ValidationCheck(this.Name,);
      
    }
```

ValidationMethod

```
  public void ValidationCheck(string name, string kana, string patientNumber, string year, string month, string days)
    {

        //Name Validation
        var regexNamePattern = @"^([a-zA-Z]){0,20}$";
        Regex nameRegex = new Regex(regexNamePattern);
        if (!nameRegex.IsMatch(name))
        {
            this.IsNameValid = "";
        }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which is the border-color that you want to change? The background color of the TextBox? Or do you want to change the color for the `TextBlock` which bind to the `ViewModel.IsNameValid`?

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to use data-binding with ValueConverter to dynamically change the color of an UIelement.

Here is a simple demo that you could refer to.

**ColorConverter:**

```
 public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = null;
        string IsNameValid = value as string;
        if (IsNameValid.Equals("123")) 
        {
            brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

  <TextBox Background="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsNameValid,Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```